# Prove inequality $(t \cdot x) + (r \cdot y) \leq (r \cdot x) + (t \cdot y)$, given $t < r$, $y < x$

Tags: inequality

I want to prove this inequality:

$$(t \cdot x) + (r \cdot y) \leq (r \cdot x) + (t \cdot y)$$

when

$t < r$

$y < x$

And $t, r, x, y$ are all constants $\geq 1$

I have tried breaking this inequality but cant seem to find a counter example, so I have tried proving it. I get stuck pretty quickly:

$$(t \cdot x) + (r \cdot y) \leq (t \cdot x) + (r \cdot y)$$
$$(t \cdot x) + (r \cdot y) \leq (r \cdot x) + (r \cdot y)$$
Here i know that $t(x) \leq r(x)$ since $t < r$, but I can't figure out how to turn $(r \cdot y)$ into $(t \cdot y)$ on the right side of the inequality. Is there a way to prove this or is there a counter example i'm not seeing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x>y$ and $r>t$. Then,

$$(r-t)(x-y)>0\implies rx-tx-ry+ty>0\implies rx+ty >tx+ry$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
x-y&>0\\
r&>t\\
\\
r(x-y)&>t(x-y)\\
rx-ry&>tx-ty\\
rx+ty&>tx+ry
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: ah i see, i will think and maybe post another answer.

Comment: You may want to google / read about Renata’s inequality and Greedy theorem. So many inequalities are derived from these concepts.